# How to achieve same heights for overline above 'a' and 'b'?

Tags: math-mode

In math mode, I tried to type in `$$\overline{a}+\overline{b}$$`, and this happened:

[image]

Obviously, the lines over `a` and `b` look different. How do I fix this?

Comment: They're different widths because `a` and `b` are different widths.  They're different heights because `a` and `b` are different heights.  Which are you trying to "fix"?

Comment: The heights. This is pretty insignificant but still, it bugs me.

Comment: Replace `a` with `a\mathstrut` (_and_ `b\mathstrut`) or `a\vphantom{b}` (preferred).

Comment: If you are using LaTeX, don't use `$$`.

Comment: Regarding cfr's comment, use `\[...\]` instead of `$$...$$`. See here: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/503/why-is-preferable-to

Comment: Use `\bar{a}` and `\bar{b}`; don't worry about the height.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I wouldn't worry about the height and use `\bar` instead of `\overline`. Compare the results below: odd numbered lines have no adjustment, even numbered lines have `\vphantom{b}` to raise the bar; the first two lines use `\overline`, the next ones use `\bar`.

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article} % twocolum just for a smaller picture
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{gather}
\overline{a}+\overline{b} \\
\overline{a\vphantom{b}}+\overline{b} \\
\bar{a}+\bar{b} \\
\bar{a\vphantom{b}}+\bar{b}
\end{gather}

\end{document}
```

[image]